# apache httpd error: "mod_rewrite: can't access DBM RewriteMap file"

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403

I'm running a fresh httpd install on Fedora linux and all my static content 403s.

The error_log shows this:

```
mod_rewrite: can't access DBM RewriteMap file
```

How do I fix this?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may be using an old config file or something has been uncommented in an example file that shouldn't have been.

Check through your apache configuration files looking for something like

```
RewriteMap examplemap dbm=sdbm:/etc/apache/mapfile.dbm
```

If you find something similar either comment it out (put a # at the start of the line) or put a suitable file in the location it's looking.